# matlab database toolbox fetch max row limit

Tags: database, matlab, fetch

I am executing the database toolbox fetch function as simply

```
curs = exec(conn,sqlQuery);
fetched = fetch(curs);
```

and therefore should be getting the default max row limit of infinity, however the function is only returning 90,000 rows (there should be more than 180k).

Does anyone know why the fetch function would be truncating my results?

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that the problem is not on the server side ?

Comment: if it is not a server side's problem then you should read: [this](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/preference-settings-for-large-data-import.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to limit the batch size with:

```
bsize   = 80000; %where bsize < NumberOfRow 

setdbprefs('FetchInBatches','yes') %you divide your result into smaller part.
setdbprefs('FetchBatchSize','h')   %you fix the size of each part

curs    = exec(conn,sqlQuery); 
fetched = fetch(curs);
```

if it's still don't work, it could be possible that the matlab's variable cannot support this amount of data so you can replace the last line with:

```
vsize   = 85000; %variable size
fetched = fetch(curs,vsize);
```